# Merge two sorted linked lists: space complexity

Tags: linked-list

I am looking at the [following Geeks for Geeks problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/1):

> Given two sorted linked lists consisting of **N and M** nodes respectively. The task is to merge both of the list (in-place) and return head of the merged list.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> ```
> Input:
> N = 4, M = 3  
> valueN[] = {5,10,15,40}  
> valueM[] = {2,3,20}  
> Output: 2 3 5 10 15 20 40   
> Explanation: After merging the two linked
> lists, we have merged list as 2, 3, 5,
> 10, 15, 20, 40.
> ```

Below answer is the GFG answer. I don't understand how its space complexity is O(1). We are creating a new node, so it must be O(m+n).

```cpp
Node* sortedMerge(Node* head1, Node* head2)  
{  
    struct Node *dummy = new Node(0);  
    struct Node *tail = dummy;  
    while (1) {  
        if (head1 == NULL) {  
            tail->next = head2;  
            break;  
        }  
        else if (head2 == NULL) {  
            tail->next = head1;  
            break;  
        }
        if (head1->data <= head2->data){
            tail->next = head1;
            head1 = head1->next;
        }
        else{
            tail->next = head2;
            head2 = head2->next;
        }
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    return dummy->next;     
}
```

Could someone explain how the space complexity is O(1) here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't understand how it's space complexity is O(1). Since we are creating a new node so it must be O(m+n).

Why should it be O(m+n) when it creates *one* node? The size of that node is a constant, so one node represents O(1) space complexity. Creating one node has nothing to do with the size of either of the input lists. Note that the node is created outside of the loop.

It is actually done this way to keep the code simple, but the merge could be done even without that `dummy` node.

Comment: Oh , I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In C or C++, a pointer to pointer to node could be used instead of a dummy node, without needing conditional code (if statement) to handle the first node, but for languages like Java, a dummy node is commonly used. The question doesn't specify a language.